# Python Telebot API. How can i use editMessageReplyMarkup method?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make my inline button disappear after a click. After a search, i found editMessageReplyMarkup method.

```
bot.editMessageReplyMarkup()
```

But I receive this error

```
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'editMessageReplyMarkup'
```

Could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.edit_message_reply_markup()` ([Source](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/apihelper.py#L636))

Please, look at pyTelegramBotAPI module source code (especially `apihelper.py` file).